# How to create MockNdefMessages

Tags: java, android, nfc

I am using FakeTagsActivity

> FakeTagsActivity — A activity that launches tags as if they had been
>   scanned. This is useful if you don't have access to NFC enabled device
>   or tag.

It define some fake data:

```
 /**
     * A plain text tag in english.
     */
    public static final byte[] ENGLISH_PLAIN_TEXT =
        new byte[] {(byte) 0xd1, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x1c, (byte) 0x54, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x65,
            (byte) 0x6e, (byte) 0x53, (byte) 0x6f, (byte) 0x6d, (byte) 0x65, (byte) 0x20,
            (byte) 0x72, (byte) 0x61, (byte) 0x6e, (byte) 0x64, (byte) 0x6f, (byte) 0x6d,
            (byte) 0x20, (byte) 0x65, (byte) 0x6e, (byte) 0x67, (byte) 0x6c, (byte) 0x69,
            (byte) 0x73, (byte) 0x68, (byte) 0x20, (byte) 0x74, (byte) 0x65, (byte) 0x78,
            (byte) 0x74, (byte) 0x2e};
```

How can i make my own data like this?

Regards

Comment: A very useful link to create your own Messages... http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3_r1/com/android/apps/tag/MockNdefMessages.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is a so-called NDEF message, containing one or more NDEF records. You can create them using the classes [`NdefMessage`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefMessage.html) and [`NdefRecord`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefRecord.html). A record has a type and a payload (the data) and sometimes an ID.

The example you show is an NDEF message with a Text record. The exact details for that kind of record (and others) can be obtained from the [NFC Forum site](http://www.nfc-forum.org/specs/spec_list/).

Answer (score 1):

I have created an [NDEF editor](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/) as an Eclipse plugin which will let you define a lot of 'fake' data in the form of files.

Loading files from the res/raw directory is easy.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like

```
new byte[] {(byte) 0xd1, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x1c, (byte) 0x54, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x65,
        (byte) 0x6e,
```

Is the NFC tag header ("�Ten") and the rest is the actual text ("Some random english text.")

**Edit** - please note that some of those numbers don't translate to visible characters (0x01 and 0x02)- That's why there are 6 number sequences and only 4 characters.  This is also why they had to build out the byte[] like they are doing (instead of just using a string) -  simply copying "�Ten" into a string will not be the same thing - so don't try :-)

those bytes are hex code for ASCII characters - I could decode them with PHP -

```
php -r "print chr(0xd1).chr(0x01).chr(0x1c).chr(0x54) . chr(0x02) . chr(0x65).chr(0x6e).chr(0x53).chr(0x6f).chr(0x6d).chr(0x65).chr(0x20).chr(0x72).chr(0x61).chr(0x6e).chr(0x64).chr(0x6f).chr(0x6d).chr(0x20).chr(0x65).chr(0x6e).chr(0x67).chr(0x6c).chr(0x69).chr(0x73).chr(0x68).chr(0x20).chr(0x74).chr(0x65).chr(0x78).chr(0x74).chr(0x2e);"
```

> �TenSome random english text.

ASCII Table - http://www.asciitable.com/

If you want to make other tags you'll have to look up the Specifications for the type of tag you want to send - Google can help you with that

**Edit**- PHP code to convert it per your comment (I just don't feel like looking up the java functions, even if I did you'd have to write a bunch of code just to be able to run / view the output - PHP is so much faster for something like this)

```
$text = 'Some random english text.';
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) {
   print " (byte) 0x" . dechex(ord(substr($text,$i,1))) .',';
}
```

Comment: $text = 'Some random english text.';
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) {
   print " (byte) 0x" . dechex(ord(substr($text,$i,1))) .',';
}    // ->  Also- Don't forget to add the header characters like I talked about in my answer.

Comment: eww, I updated my answer - I wish you could post code in comments but I guess it's better to force you to edit your answer and keep everything in one place :-)

Comment: Hi, what's the header of string like that 1G1FP22PXS2100100 ?

Comment: Hi, i encode this string by your method: 1G1FP22PXS2100100  but i cant.